# Two linear transformations defined on same vector spaces with finite dimension.Can we say that they will have same rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Two linear transformations defined on same vector spaces with finite dimension. Can we say that they will have same rank?

I am given a problem that $f,g:V\to W$ be two linear transformation and $f$ and $g$ are respectively injective and surjective. To prove $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$.

I am thinking it like that since f is injective $\operatorname{rank}(f)=\dim(V)$ and since $g$ is surjective $\operatorname{rank}(g)=\dim(W)$.

Then to equate both of them.....but I do not understand whether it is correct or wrong.

Comment: The title sounds very strange.

Comment: Use proper tags (`self learning` is not one of them) for your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is injective, $\dim(V) \leq \dim(W)$. On the other hand, since $g$ is surjective, $\dim(V) \geq \dim(W)$. Hence $\dim(V) = \dim(W)$.

The above inequalities follow from the "Rank-Nullity Theorem":

$$ \dim(\mathrm{im}(f)) = \dim(V) - \dim(\mathrm{ker}(f)) $$

To obtain the inequalities mentioned above, note that $\dim(\mathrm{ker}(f)) = 0$ since $f$ is injective, and $\dim(\mathrm{im}(g)) = \dim(W)$ since $g$ is surjective.

They do have the same rank, because, as you say, $\dim(V) = \mathrm{rank}(f)$ and $\dim(W) = \mathrm{rank}(g)$. But you can prove that $\dim(V) = \dim(W)$ without this fact (by my reasoning above).

Comment: It could be good to mention that your statements in the first paragraph follow from the rank-nullity theorem and are not necessarily obvious.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro Good point. I've updated my answer with a little bit of explanation.